# Is it possible to plot a variable in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

For my upcoming exam project I want to analyze Donald Trump rally speeches and find out what the top 10 most common words are, and plot it by using matplotlib. I've currently run in to some trouble while trying to plot my variable "lst" where all the data is stored. Is there a way to make this work?

This is the current code I've been running - and trying to plt.plot(lst) doesn't yield great resulsts at all..

So far I've been typing it in manually, as seen at the bottom of the code.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thank you so much in advance!

(I'm very new to python and coding in general!)

```
import pandas as pd
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df_1 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/BattleCreekDec19_2019.txt")
df_2 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/BemidjiSep18_2020.txt")
df_3 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/CharlestonFeb28_2020.txt")
df_4 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/CharlotteMar2_2020.txt")
df_5 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/CincinnatiAug1_2019.txt")
df_6 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/ColoradorSpringsFeb20_2020.txt")
df_7 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/DallasOct17_2019.txt")
df_8 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/DesMoinesJan30_2020.txt")
df_9 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/FayettevilleSep9_2019.txt")
df_10 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/FayettevilleSep19_2020.txt")
df_11 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/FreelandSep10_2020.txt")
df_12 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/GreenvilleJul17_2019.txt")
df_13 = pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/HendersonSep13_2020.txt")
df_14= pd.read_table("Trump_speeches/HersheyDec10_2019.txt")


df = df_1 + df_2 + df_3 + df_4 + df_5 + df_6 + df_7 + df_8 + df_9 + df_10 + df_11 + df_12 + df_13 + df_14


def stopwords():
    return ["","a","about","above","after","again","against",.....]

def tokenizer(text, lower=True, stopword=True):
    if stopword:
        stopwordlist = stopwords()
        tokens = [token for token in text.lower().split(' ') if token not in stopwordlist]
    elif lower:
        tokens = text.lower().split()
    else:
        tokens = text.split()
    return tokens

def word_count(text, sort = True, stopword=True):
    counter = dict()
    for word in tokenizer(text, stopword=stopword):
        counter.setdefault(word, 0)
        counter[word] = counter[word] + 1
    if sort:
        counter = dict(sorted(counter.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
    return counter

wc = word_count(' '.join(df))
wc_items = wc.items()
lst = list(wc_items)[:10]
print('[INFO] Top 10 most common words in Donald Trump rally speeches:')
print(lst)



x = ["said", "great", "people", "right?", "lot", "american", "good", "love", "years", "people"]
y = [757, 693, 571, 353, 311, 267, 257, 244, 208, 203]
```

This is the current code I've been running - and trying to plt.plot(lst) doesn't yield great resulsts at all..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's also good to display the error code right in your post, it will help to find the problem.